# Overdispersion. Is it ever appropriate to have a non-linear variance correction from Poisson to a Quasi-Poisson?

Tags: regression, poisson-regression, overdispersion, quasi-likelihood

This is my first Cross Validated post. Please let me know if this is too specific/innapropriate for the site.

I am building a Poisson/quasiposson model with one predictor. The response variable consists of count data (seedling tallies in a plot), and the predictor is a continuous measure ($\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+d_{i}}$, where $n$ is the number of mature trees surrounding the plot in a given area and $d$ is the distance of those trees to the plot). When I run a Poisson family glm and estimate the variance weight $\hat{\phi}$ via  $\frac{\chi^{2}}{n-p}$ where $\chi^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(y_{i}-\mu_{i})}{var(y_i)}$, I get $\hat{\phi}=78$. Additionally, when I run a quasipoisson family glm the estimated overdispersion is roughly 84. This would suggest to reweight my variance of my Poisson to roughly 80 times the mean! I have many plots with 0-5 successes and a handful of plots with as many succesess as 450, so I could imagine that the mean of the glm could be very close to 0 across the domain, but the variance could be much larger. Is there such a thing as a variance weight for quasipoisson that is "too much" greater than the mean to accept quasipoisson as a reasonable distribution for my data?

Notably, the variance of my response appears to have a power relationship ($\mu_{i}=var(y_{i})^{2}$) with the mean of my response across the predictor domain. Would it ever be appropriate to have a nonlinear weight for a quasipoisson? I was thinking that if I could show my predictor's variance is the square of its mean across a range of uniformly distributed tree densities surrounding my plot, that I could somehow use this as a priori info to justify weighting the variance of my distributions in a non-linear way. The idea here would be that the predictor would vary much more at higher tree densities and would account for the heteroscedasticity of the response in the higher predictor values.

Comment: When describing your power relationship, do you mean $\mu_i^2 = \text{var}(y_i)$?  The way you have it written, it looks like underdispersion rather than overdispersion.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant $\mu^{2}=$ var$y_{i}$

Comment: This indicates that a negative binomial model might be appropriate.  In R, that would be `glm.nb` from the MASS package, although there is another implementation in another package that I can't at the moment remember.  Page 5 of the linked document on CRAN may help explain this.   https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/vignettes/countreg.pdf

Comment: Worked like a charm. Overdispersion was incredibly small with negative binomial.

Comment: Great!  Responses like that are why many of us answer questions on this site!